# How does inheritance work in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

What is the difference between

```
NSArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

and

```
NSMutableArray *arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

I know both (`arr1`, `dict1`, `arr2`, `dict2`) are going to create `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableDictionary` object respectively, `arr1` and `dict1` would have access to all the functions that could be accessed by `arr2` and `dict2`.

My Question to you guys is:

What is the difference between `arr1` and `arr2` or `dict1` or `dict2`? Why would any one make object like `arr1` and `dict1` when we could do same things by making objects like `arr2` and `dict2`? Are there any benefits of initializing objects like `arr1` and `dict1` over `arr2` and `dict2`? If none, what could be the use of initializing objects like this?

Answer (score 2):

`arr1` is a reference to `NSArray` which gets an instance of a specialization of `NSArray` assigned, that is `NSMutableArray`. (`NSMutableArray` class inherits from `NSArray` and adds some methods to modify the array)
The compiler will prevent you from modifying `arr1`. (However, in Obj-C you could still call the `NSMutableArray` methods on `arr1` during runtime when the object actually is of type `NSMutableArray`, but that is a different topic and not a proper way of doing it. See below for a better way of modifying `arr1` if it really is mutable.)

The same applies for `dic1`.

`arr2` and `dict2` on the contrary are references to `NSMutableSomething`. Therefore those methods that belong to the mutable classes but not to their immutable base class can be accessed in code.

Some addition: Later in your code you could assign (and cast) `arr1` to `arr2` and then access the methods of `NSMutableArray`. Before assigning and casting a reference to a base class to a reference to a specialzation, you should always check the current class by `isKindOfClass:` method of `NSObject`. 
Sampe:

```
if ([arr1 isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
    arr2 = (NSMutableArray*) arr1;
    // Do something with arr2 that requires its mutability. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mutable types have some special privileges like runtime update/insert/delete object from collection.

But they must have to be initialise before use and they occupies more memory than immutable.

Where else immutable type collection can not be alter at runtime. They are static containers as and contains elements which can't be alter from collection.

Immutable does not need to be `alloc init` and they consume less memory than mutable.

Answer (score 0):

In short NSArray is not flexible. You can't add or remove object into it. Same goes for NSDictionary. You can initialize but dynamic cast will occur and you will have in arr1 simply NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

Difference is simple

> 1-Mutable classes are those which could be changed after initialization but other can't be changed using SetObject: or SetValue: etc.
>
> 2-Mutable classes dynamically create on heap other are created on stack.

```
I prefer immutable on mutable because if mutable is exposed then other can 
change its data using setobject or setvalue and may be we don't know about it.

but if immutable is exposed then we can't change its data so data remain protected.
```